# private data member in C++ OOP

Tags: oop, private

I am new to OOP in C++. I got a doubt. I know it may be a silly doubt.
In the code below in main function, commented line will give error as I can not access private data memebers directly. but in the member function `complex add(complex &C)` I created a object `temp` of class `complex`. How can I access the data member of object `temp` directly and modify them as those are private. Like in the main function, should it not throw error? Is there any rule that in the member function of class we can access private data of a object of same class directly.

```
using namespace std;

class complex{
  private:
  int real;
  int img;
  
  public:
  complex(int r = 0, int i = 0);
  complex add(complex &C);
};

complex :: complex(int r, int i){
  real = r;
  img = i;
}

complex complex :: add(complex &C){
  complex temp;
  temp.real = real + C.real;
  temp.img = img + C.img;
  return temp;
}


int main() {
  
  complex c1(3,4);
  complex c2(5,7);
  complex c3;
  // c3.real = 3;
  // c3.img = 5;
  c3 = c1.add(c2);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try and stick to rule, keep your member variables private, if you need to change them or access them once the object is created, use a public get / set function.

e.g:

```
int complex::GetReal() const { return m_real; }

void complex::SetReal(const int i) { m_real = i; }
```